# File upload as image

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I go about making an file upload input appear as an image.

For example, Facebook and Twitter have image icons for their image file uploads.

Thank you,

Brian

Comment: you mean, for the button in the form?

Comment: I mean for the input and the button.  Like on Facebook and Twitter there's a singe button that a user clicks to upload an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [EXAMPLE fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ees2q/)

The 'input' has a style: `display:none;`, than just do:

```
$('#upload_img').click(function(){
    $('#upload').click();
});
```

Comment: ahh now I understand. I'll try that out

Comment: (+1) It could not be more explicit!

Answer (score 2):

Sufficiently recent browsers allow you to call `click()` on the `<input type="file">` element during the click event for another element, such as an image. (If you don't wait for a click event, you will probably get a blocked popup warning.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard goto HTML-only method of doing what I think you're asking:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

basically, you place you browse image somewhere, and you overlay the `<input type="file" />` with opacity set to `0`.

It works in browsers as old as css opacity filters are. Alternatives include [flash](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/02/26/yui-blog-improving-the-flickr-upload-exprience-with-yui-uploader/) and calling `.click()` on the input element.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that out. Not sure how the .click() method helps me.